# how to convert the text into timing for subtitle

Tags: youtube, subtitles

I have a video which is take 6 hours and 31 minutes which I want to get the subtitle from youtube but i couldn't be able to do as they are take the video for 1 hour only. I have uploaded each video of each hour on youtube to get subtitles.

However, I have put the subtitles altogether and I have removed the timing for each subtitle file from each video.

Here is the list of what the file is look like:

```
was a salesman



again and saw how they can see how they
got because I love buying stuff right



see gotta love to buy stuff



right from people that love to sell
stuff that's number one number two



buy stuff often from people that are
good at selling stuff



right and the number three just do what
they did



right you're in a little



by seeing me sell today and I it's gonna
be a you know the minority of what I'm



doing
...etc
```

I want to convert those into timing:

```
1
00:00:00,099 --> 00:00:03,144
was a salesman

2
00:00:03,549 --> 00:00:06,590
again and saw how they can see how they
got because I love buying stuff right

3
00:00:06,959 --> 00:00:08,550
see gotta love to buy stuff

4
00:00:08,055 --> 00:00:11,092
right from people that love to sell
stuff that's number one number two

5
00:00:11,092 --> 00:00:14,133
buy stuff often from people that are
good at selling stuff

6
00:00:15,033 --> 00:00:18,035
right and the number three just do what
they did

7
00:00:18,053 --> 00:00:22,114
right you're in a little

8
00:00:23,014 --> 00:00:26,111
by seeing me sell today and I it's gonna
be a you know the minority of what I'm
```

Do you know how i can convert the text into timing?

I have tried to put the text into timing on youtube, but it won't allow me because the video is too large. it will be able to do the timing for 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have removed the timings there is no way to recreate them for each video and maintain sync.  You should have left each hour subtitle segment with timings intact and adjusted each succeeding subtitle timings from the end of the preceding one.

If the first hour subtitles ended at say, 01:01:10.000 and the next subtitle set started at 00:00:01.544 then it could have been altered to 01:01:11.554 (01:01:10.000 + 00:00:01.554) with a program such as subtitle edit.  Then the subtitles could have been joined and been in sync with the movie.

An alternative way to get subtitles is with FFMPEG:

FOR ASS SUBTITLE
"c:\PathToFFMPEG\ffmpeg.exe" -i "c:\PathToVideo\VideoFile.mp4" -vn -an -map 0:TrackIDtoExtract> -c:s:0 ass "NewSub.ass"

FOR SRT SUBTITLE
"c:\PathToFFMPEG\ffmpeg.exe" -i "c:\PathToVideo\VideoFile.mp4" -vn -an -map 0:TrackIDtoExtract -c:s:0 srt "NewSub.srt"

To list the tracks use
"c:\PathToFFMPEG\ffmpeg.exe" -i "c:\PathToVideo\VideoFile.mp4"

EXAmple: "c:\user\xxx\desktop\ffmpeg.exe" -i "c:\user\xxx\desktop\VideoFile.mp4" -vn -an -map 0:2 -c:s:0 srt "c:\user\xxx\desktop\NewSub.srt"